# reproductor de audio html no reproduce los link de radio en vivo

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

estoy desarrollando un reproductor de radio en vivo el cual desde carga las URL en me da los siguientes errores en la consola y no se ejecuta

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta name="name" content="Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
        <!-- Lo de abajo es para evitar que el navegador guarde el Caché. -->     
        <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
        <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
        <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />


        <link rel="stylesheet" href="EMISORA/css/bootstrap.min.css" />    

        <script src="EMISORA/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
```

estas son las cabeceras que utilizo.

y aca esta el body de la pagina

```
    <body>
<a class="centrado" href="iniciar_sesion.php" target="_blank"> Registrar Emisoras </a>
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 cuerpo">
  <div>
    <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-sm-12">
      <h3 class="titulo"><span class="verde">EMISORAS</span> ONLINE</h3>
    </div>
    <label for="busqueda" class="fuentePais">PAÍS</label><br />


    <select id="pais" class="selectPais" name="pais" onchange="buscarEmisoras()">
              <option value="#"> Seleccione Pais</option>
              <?php  
              foreach ($paisesCombo as $key => $combo) {
              ?>
              <option value="<?php echo $combo;  ?>"><?php echo $combo;  ?></option>
              <?php    
              }
                // aca cerramos el ciclo while */
              ?>
              <input type="hidden" name="oldPais" id="oldPais">
    </select>
  </div>

  <div id="divemisoras">
    <label for="emisoras" class="labelfuenteEmisora">EMISORA</label>
    <select id="emisoras" class=" selectEmisora" onchange="playEmisora()">
      <option value="select">-->Selecciona una Emisora</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-sm-12 al" id="emisoras">
    <label for="E001" id="labelemisora"></label><br />
    <audio
      id="E001"
      class="emisora"
      controlsList="download"
      src=""
      autoplay
      loop
      preload="auto"
    ></audio>
  </div>
  <div id="botones" class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12 botonesPP">
    <a href="#"><img onclick="togglePlay()" id="imgpp" src="EMISORA/PAUSE.png" width="65" height="65" /></a>
    <p class="timer">
      <span id="horas">00</span>:<span id="minutos">00</span>:<span
        id="segundos"
        >00</span
      >
    </p>
  </div>
</div>

<br>      
<!--<input class="centrado" type="button" name="registrar" id="registrar" value="registrar" onclick="window.open('registar_emisora.php')">-->
```

el reproductor funciono perfectamente con este codigo hasta el dia de ayer que realize mas ruebas aunas nuevas url en base64 que estaba decodificando, pero al colocar la url directa igual me genera los siguientes mensajes

> URI inválido. Carga de recurso de medios  falló.
>
> "Content-Type" HTTP de "text/html" no está soportado. Carga de recurso
>   de medios https://vivo.biobiochile.cl/player/?radio=santiago falló.
>
> No se pueden reproducir medios. No hay decodificadores para los
>   formatos solicitados: text/html

la url que trato de reproducir desde la pagina es

> https://vivo.biobiochile.cl/player/?radio=santiago

Answer (score 2):

Pues efectivamente va a retornar error, estás cargando un archivo html a un reproductor de audio, por otro lado, buscando en las fuentes encontré el link de la transmisión:

> https://redirector.dps.live/biobiosantiago/aac/icecast.audio

Si reemplazas *acc* en el link por *mp3* por ejemplo, recibirás el audio en este formato.

Puedes probarlo en el siguiente ejemplo:

```html
<audio controls src="https://redirector.dps.live/biobiosantiago/mp3/icecast.audio"></audio>
```

Espero que te sea de ayuda, un saludo.

Comment: realize el cambio y siguen apareciendo los mismos errores en la consola

Comment: No tengo ningún error en consola al cargar el recurso, puedes [ver este fiddle](https://playcode.io/470504?tabs=index.html,preview,console) y en su [versión de producción](https://470504.playcode.io) y aun así no estoy capturando ningún error en consola, en que navegador estas trabajando?

Comment: estoy trabajando con chrome y con firefox para probar, en el chrome era que me salian esos errores pero creo que era por que las url que estaba guardando tenian caracteres especiales como "{}"

Comment: Puedes modificar tu pregunta y adjuntar tu Javascript para observar cómo estás introduciendo las URL?